# Creating a PostgreSQL record via unique email in RubyOnRails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, email

I hope you are well.

I need to **generate unique email for users and allow them to send email to create a new post** in their profile.

---

Example flow

1. User signs up
2. User gets username-withsomeuniqueaddition@myproduct.com
3. User send email to the address above
4. The product creates a record with the info from email body

---

Similar to how users can save links to their Instapaper account using email.

---

I spent hours googling but it all return how to send emails with RoR.

Is there any direction, tutorial or gem you can guide me?

Thank you, stay safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate unique email"? I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: As for the second half of your question, here is the rails documentation on handling inbound emails: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html

Comment: @TomLord hi Tom, thank you for the comment. I just updated the question with more info.   I basically need user to be able to create in entry not via Post New form but via an email. Similar to for example how you can save things to your Instapaper account via email

Comment: To generate `withsomeuniqueaddition`, you could use `user.id`?? Or if you want it to be "unguessable", then use something like `SecureRandom.uuid` or `SecureRandom.alphanumeric`?

Comment: As for the second part of the question, isn't that what the documentation I linked to describes? Without a more specific question, I'm not sure what advise I can give other than repeating the documentation in an answer. If you have a partial solution, and have stumbled into an error/confusion/unexpected behaviour, then could you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: @TomLord Ah apologies mate, I guess I misunderstood what I read. I thought it was referring to Sending Emails from Rails, but your link clearly says "Receiving email to application"! Thank you! How can I nominate your help as Awesome Solution?